# Please Explain the concept behind this, difference between (ptr and *ptr in c programming)

Tags: c, pointers, variables

```c
#include <stdio.h>

struct Student {
    int id;
    char name[20];
};
    
int main() {
    struct Student stu;  
    struct Student *ptr = &stu;  
        
    ptr->id = 101;
    strcpy(ptr->name, "John Doe");
            
    printf("Student ID: %d\n", ptr->id);
    printf("Student Name: %s\n", ptr->name);
    
    // explain the below code 
    printf("%d\n", (void *)ptr);
    printf("%d\n", &stu);
    printf("%d\n", *ptr);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Explain the pointer part the code which I have commented.
and also do explain `(void*)`: I am confused why `ptr` and `*ptr` have the same memory.

Comment: Take out a pen and some paper. Draw two boxes on the paper, label one `stu` and the other `ptr`. Draw an arrow from `ptr` to `stu`. That's basically how pointers works. When you do `*ptr` you start at the box `ptr`, and follow the arrow to the box that it points to, to get the object `stu`.

Comment: Presumably the backslash in `struct Student\* ptr = &stu;` isn't in your real code?

Comment: Please note that to print a pointer with `printf` you should be using the `%p` format, which expects a `void *` argument (you *must* cast the argument if it's not correct). The `%d` format is for `int`. Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: From the above note about `printf`, and knowing that `*ptr` is the same as the `stu` structure object, then it's easy to understand that using `%d` to print a `struct Student` would not work. In fact, if your compiler doesn't complain about it then you need to enable more warnings when building.

Answer (score 2):

`ptr` is a pointer referencing the struct `stu`.

`&` is the "address of" operator. The address of `stu` is the same pointer that `ptr` points to.

`*` is the indirection ("object pointed to by") operator. `*ptr` is in fact `stu`. As you've seen, you can technically print it out as an integer with `%d`, but it makes very little sense to do so. It does not (or at least, should not), print the same value as `ptr`. See, e.g.:
https://onlinegdb.com/3DmUu2ftv

Answer (score 0):

`ptr` is a pointer to a `Student struct` and `&stu` is the address of a `Student struct`, they both have the same value as you initialized `ptr = &stu` so printing the value of `ptr` and that of `&stu` should produce the same output, but the code posted has undefined behavior:

- `printf("%d\n", (void *)ptr)` `%d` expects an `int`, not a `void *`, this has undefined behavior. Use this instead:

  ```
  printf("%p\n", (void *)ptr);
  ```
- `printf("%d\n", &stu)` same remark. Use this instead:

  ```
  printf("%p\n", (void *)&stu);
  ```
- `printf("%d\n", *ptr)` has undefined behavior as you are passing a `struct Student` by value, which `printf` cannot handle and it is expecting an `int`.  There is no portable way to print structures directly, you must print their members individually.

`*ptr` is the structure itself pointed to by `str`.

Answer (score 0):

When you point on something, then there is a difference between your finger (the reference) and the thing you are pointing to. `ptr` is the "finger" and `*ptr` is the thing it is pointing to.

`ptr` is `&stu`.

`*ptr` is `stu`.

So, `ptr` vs. `*ptr` is "finger" vs. "the thing". Except when you declare your pointer, that is, when you have the below:

```
struct Student *ptr = &stu;
```

the `*ptr` in this specific case is just specifying that `ptr` will be a `struct Student *`, that is, in the above, the `*` is part of the type specification.

Answer (score 0):

After the line

```
struct Student *ptr = &stu;
```

the following relationships are true:

```
 ptr == &stu // struct Student * == struct Student *
*ptr ==  stu // struct Student   == struct Student
```

The *expressions* `ptr` and `&stu` evaluate to the *address* of the `stu` variable.  These two lines are *attempting* to print that address value:

```
printf("%d\n", (void *)ptr);
printf("%d\n", &stu);
```

but they get it wrong; the proper way to print pointer values is to use the `p` conversion specifier *and* to cast the expression to `void *`:

```
printf( "%p\n", (void *) ptr );
printf( "%p\n", (void *) &stu );
```

The `(void *)` is a *cast* - it means "treat the following expression as if it had the type pointer to `void`".  The `p` conversion specifier expects its corresponding argument to have type `void *`.  Normally you don't need to explicitly cast a pointer value to `void *`, but because of how `printf`'s arguments are handled you need to here.

The *expressions* `*ptr` and `stu` evaluate to the `stu` variable itself; `*ptr` acts as a kinda-sorta-but-not-really alias for the variable `stu`.

This line:

```
printf("%d\n", *ptr);
```

is just plain *wrong*.  The `d` conversion specifier expects its corresponding argument to have type `int`, but the *expression* `*ptr` has type `struct Student`.  What the original author of the code is counting on is that because the first member of the struct (`id`) is an integer, this code will print that integer value.

And in practice it will -- *sometimes*.  The behavior is *undefined*, meaning the compiler isn't required to handle it in any particular way, and you should not expect any particular result.  That line *should* be written as

```
printf( "%d\n", ptr->id );
```